# Cannot update macOS and error while installing Rosetta

Tags: macos, wifi

I just bought a new MacBook Air M2 and after I connected to WiFi everything worked fine at first. The problem began when I tried to update the Mac. It says that I am not connected to the Internet but, I can still browse.   This error also occurs when I try to install Rosetta.

What's causing this problem and what can I do to fix?

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting problem, can you try opening Applications > Utilities > Terminal and then typing/pressing RETURN: softwareupdate --list-full-installers What happens then?